# Extension on chrome to view full URL in Google Search?

Tags: chrome

[image]

Is there a Google Chrome Extension that I could use on Google Search so that when I hover over links like these in Google Search or hover my mouse over it, it displays the webpage URL in some type of hover box where I can copy it?

When I right click on the link(s) and click copy, it gives me a URL like this

> https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8Q6QUoATAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hobsonscoursefinder.com.au%2FLatest-news%2FGetting-into-university&ei=JSPNU4_SD8rr8AWXvIBI&usg=AFQjCNGwMHq3MV5ztscUCC1x9OPThiGrqg&sig2=zq_qzHzAEqiAFZ8R_jtmYg&bvm=bv.71198958,d.dGc

Any ideas/suggestions? I just want to see the actual website URL and be able to hover over these URL's and see them in some type of hover box so I can copy it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like [Undirect](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/undirect/dohbiijnjeiejifbgfdhfknogknkglio) for that. It doesn't do *exactly* what you want but I personally think it is better.

It removes the redirect link and replaces it with the direct link. This has the benefit of preventing Google from doing *as* much tracking and also right-click->copy link address actually copies the link address instead of that ugly ugly redirect address.

Comment: no longer works for Google

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Chrome Browser has fixed this for themselves. Firefox still has this problem.

None of these solutions work or do it with a utility or tool.

https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/copy-crapfree-urls-googles-search-results/

https://superuser.com/questions/1204421/how-do-i-copy-a-hyperlink-without-the-stuff-past-html

https://superuser.com/questions/264584/when-copying-a-link-from-a-google-search-how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-www-google-co

https://superuser.com/questions/492040/how-can-i-copy-the-link-in-google-without-openning-the-link-and-the-google-stuf

https://superuser.com/questions/480639/prevent-google-from-rewriting-search-results-link